# php file_get_contents behaves differently on dev and production

Tags: php, curl, wget

EDIT : the reason was reblaze service (security) which blocked us. Please ignore the question

I checked the other similar questions, this case seems to be different.

I have this simple code:

```
$src='http://www.fattal.co.il/Octopus/Upload/Images/Pages/thumbs/magic-sunrise-club-eilat-youth-club_thumb.jpg';

$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'user_agent' =>  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0'
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$data=  file_get_contents( $src, false, $context, -1, 1500000);
echo strlen ($data);
```

On my dev pc it prints out 8861 - the real size of the image. On the linux ubuntu production server it brings some HTML code that loads javascript from the site (the size printed is 549 bytes).

both boxes fetch images nicely from other sites. So the wrappers seems to be in place. This issue is specific to the site in the example.
I tried emulating a server with many header variations. Included all the possible headers that a browser would send. This doesnt make a difference.

I tried from another production server to rule out that the image server blocked it by IP.

The two boxes have allow_url_fopen On.

What else can I check to understand why its not working on the production server?

Comment: You might be interested to learn about $http_response_header - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php and get_headers() - http://php.net/get_headers and stream_notification_callback() - http://php.net/stream_notification_callback for your context

Comment: Great idea. 
both return 200 with headers that represent the fact that the 'good serever' receives an image and the 'bad' gets HTML.
Unique headers to the good server:

'Accept-Ranges: bytes'
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
'Cache-Control: max-age=604800'
'Content-Type: image/jpeg' 
'ETag: "8afd6619a884cf1:0"'
'Last-Modified: Tue, 10 Jun 2014 12:32:53 GMT'

headers unique to the 'bad' call:
"Cache-Control: no-cache, private, no-transform, no-store"
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
"expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT"
"PageSpeed: off"

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, I loaded the file up with FireFox and used the Modify Headers extension to filter the Host parameter. It returned an error with a size similar to yours. Try adding the Host header set to www.fattal.co.il. See if that works

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the reason is reblaze security platform that the site uses. We just need to get white listed.

Thanks !